# Emptying Angular typeahead input after click

Tags: angular, input, rxjs, observable, typeahead

I have a typeahead dropdown and when you click it it shows out-of-date values, so I want to make it so that when it's clicked on it shows nothing (until you type). The typeahead functionality itself is working.

Originally I was thinking that the change had to be made within my component file (e.g. emptying the field), but it looks like it might be made within the template (or within the comp and template files).

I'm very new to Angular so I apologize if my syntax/code/etc is rusty.

**Component file:**

```js
// locations
  filteredLocations: Observable<any[]>;
  filteredUserLocations: Observable<any[]>;
  locationTargeting = 'My Location';

getMyLocations(search: string): void {
    const user = this.auth.account$.getValue();
    if (!search.includes(';') && this.locationTargeting === 'My Location') {
// this.filteredUserLocations = new Observable<any[]>(); // tried setting this here (and in other locations), but the typeahead history still appears
      this.filteredUserLocations = this.locationService
      .getTypeaheadLocationsByValue(
        search, // value
        user.id, // accountId
        null, // accountIds
        this.targetingFormGroup.get('groups')?.value) // groupIds
        .pipe(map((result: CollectionResponse<LocationSearchResponse>) => {
          if (result.list) {
            result.list.map((location) => this.addToLocationCache(location.id, location.locationNumber, location.name));
          }

          return result.list && result.list.length > 0 ? [{ label: 'User Locations', values: (result.list || []) }] : [];
        }));

    } else {
      this.filteredUserLocations = new Observable<any[]>();
    }
  }
```

---

**Service file:**

```js
getTypeaheadLocationsByValue(
    value: string,
    accountId: string,
    accountIds: string[] = null,
    groupIds: string[] = null
  ): Observable<CollectionResponse<LocationSearchResponse>> {
    const searchLocationTypeahead: SearchLocationsTypeaheadByValueRequest = new SearchLocationsTypeaheadByValueRequest();
    if (accountIds) {
      // etc
    }
    if (groupIds) {
      // etc
    }
    searchLocationTypeahead.value = value;
    searchLocationTypeahead.accountId = accountId;

    return this.http.post<CollectionResponse<LocationSearchResponse>>('my-url', searchLocationTypeahead);
  }
```

---

**Template file:**

```
          <div *ngIf="hasLocationTargeting" class="add-container">
            <mat-form-field>
              <input autofocus matInput formControlName="locationToAdd"
                data-atm="target-locations-input" [matAutocomplete]="location">
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you defined your formControlName, therefore you just use the methods provided by **Reactive Forms.**

resetting the whole form:

```
this.targetingFormGroup.reset();
```

or patching a Value

```
this.targetingFormGroup.get('locationToAdd').patchValue('');
```

This should do the trick. For further research, check out Reactive Forms: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: Thanks for the info (it makes sense to set the form to a "default" state), however change detection is causing the typeahead dropdown to fire repeatedly when patchValue is run (`this.targetingFormGroup.get('locationToAdd').patchValue('');)` (it makes the dropdown disappear and reappear). Would I have to detach the view, do `patchValue`, and then re-attach the view? Or is there a simpler way to go about it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of handling this. One such way is initially setting the value to null / empty array. You can do that like this:

```
// locations
  filteredLocations: Observable<any[]>;
  filteredUserLocations: Observable<any[]>;
  locationTargeting = 'My Location';

getMyLocations(search: string): void {
/********* Before you do the actual search, set the observable to null ******/
this.filteredUserLocations = of([]); // This will initially have an empty array and then you can set the value when you want
    

const user = this.auth.account$.getValue();
    if (!search.includes(';') && this.locationTargeting === 'My Location') {
    
this.filteredUserLocations = this.locationService
      .getTypeaheadLocationsByValue(....)
```